# I resized partition and deleted swap area , how do I update the /etc/fstab file to reenable swap?

Tags: 14.04, swap, fstab

This is my current fstab file content:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=d5d25cbb-a5ab-4c28-92cd-3d1037563ec3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
#UUID=1672c5d6-df35-432a-b850-23a1b7886bc3 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

this is the sudo blkid output....

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Disco HDD" UUID="5ED2B771D2B74C51" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Reservado para el sistema" UUID="34DA6223DA61E19A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e0ef6fba-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="5E9266DB9266B765" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e0ef6fba-02"
/dev/sdb4: UUID="d5d25cbb-a5ab-4c28-92cd-3d1037563ec3" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e0ef6fba-04"
/dev/sdb5: LABEL="swap" UUID="a3a1b9ea-266d-47c8-955f-74a16e53a696" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="e0ef6fba-05"
```

Apparently they have differen UUID's......

[image]

How should I update the fstab file so I can reactivate the swap to the new values?

EDIT:

This is the output of the swapon -s command, what does it mean??is the swap partition I created being used?

```
Filename     Type            Size     Used  Priority
/dev/sdb5   partition       3070972     0      -1
```

Comment: Just change the UUID in fstab to the new one.

Comment: but the line of the swap UUID it's commented, will that have any effect?......could you create and answer with the proper UUID replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new line should look like this, given the above data:

```
UUID=a3a1b9ea-266d-47c8-955f-74a16e53a696 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Basically, you just change the old UUID to the new one, and uncomment the line.

Comment: really good answer my friend, thanks, I'm leaving windows behind for good and I'm learning on a daily basis...do I have to do something else after updating the file?: Is there some way to verify is the swap is being used correctly right now?

Comment: You can run `swapon -s` to check if swap is enabled.